# Load code directly to RAM through SWD / on STM32H7

Tags: gdb, stm32, openocd

I need to load a small piece of code directly to the internal RAM of a STM32H753 part from the IDE (which is STM32CubeIDE) using OpenOCD or ST GDB server. I'm working on a STM32H753I-EVAL2 board and I load the part and debug through SWD with the STLinkv3 probe.

I don't want to load the code to the Flash and then copy it to RAM at runtime, it's really about loading the code directly to RAM from the IDE.

I've generated the binary with the right code mapped into RAM (I checked with `readelf`) but when I launch the debug session in Eclipse/STM32CubeIDE, the RAM is not written.

Is it possible to do that ? Is there something special to set up in the IDE ?

EDIT: I tried to load the very same .elf with STM32CubeProgrammer and it worked fine ie. I can see that the RAM is loaded as expected. So it looks like there is either a limitation of the IDE / ST GDB server or a setup I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out. It is simply a bug/limitation of STLink GDB Server. It is actually working fine with OpenOCD gdb server.